# Scrolling on iPad for an iframe within GWT window

Tags: ipad, iframe, scroll, gxt

PLEASE NOTE: This is not a "use two fingers to scroll" problem. Whether it is one finger, or two, or three, or the whole hand, for some reason our iframe does not scroll on an iPad. :)

Here is the scenario:

In our web application, which is built using EXT-GWT, we have a few windows that open as (maximized) pop-ups and present some forms to the users. These forms, which are most of the times external, are rendered in an iFrame and some of the forms have their content collapsed at the initial load - the user can choose to expand any section of the form, fill it in and submit. Now everything works fine except the scrolling in iPad. After the iframe's content is loaded and collapsed (collapsing is done using JS on the client side, basically, the content loads as expanded by default and then is collapsed by JS) iPad just fails to provide scolling to the iframe. Even after the content of the iframe is expanded the iframe does not get any scrolling.

As of now, we have solved this problem by increasing the height (using JavaScript) of the EXT-GWT window to the size of the expanded iframe body content. This makes the whole window scrollable, instead of just the iframe within the window. While it works, the window becomes way to big, so I was wondering if there is any better way for us to provide scrolling to the iframe.

Thanks for the help,
Nitin

Comment: any help/suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying (almost) everything, I have come to the conclusion that increasing the GWT window height to the iframe.body.height is the only solution for getting the window/iframe to scroll on iPad. Hopefully, this will help someone in future.

Comment: how to set the height for GWT window?

Comment: You can call the setHeight() method on the window.

Comment: Can you scroll inside the iframe? If I set the iframe-height = gwt-rootpanel-height I can only scroll outside the iframe. Inside the iframe, only the text will be selected if I want to scroll with one finger.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices you need set overflow: auto; or the scrolling won't work. For my web apps I used fancybox to display iframes modally and once I change the overflow setting in the css file the two finger scroll worked perfectly on the iPad.

Comment: Thanks Ske. I am pretty sure that I tried overflow: auto; on the iframe, but it never worked. Anyways, the problem is solved for now...will give it a shot again whenever I can. Thanks for posting the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty new to GWT, but for me it worked like this:

The parent-div of the iframe has a class in my case, x-component.
I made an entry to my css file like this:
.x-component{-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow:auto;}

It works as well if I set these entries not to the class, but to the div-element itself.

Hope that helps